# Phonegap Email Composer

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to port my existing iOS application to android, haven't done any tweaks yet just a quick & dirt try.

So I used 'phonegap build android' and imported the android files to eclipse now if I want to start it on my tab 4 I got the following error log:

```
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767): Process: de.mo.mepantrag, PID: 26767
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider de.appplant.cordova.plugin.emailcomposer.AttachmentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.emailcomposer.AttachmentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.mo.mepantrag-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/de.mo.mepantrag-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5118)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4710)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4593)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.emailcomposer.AttachmentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.mo.mepantrag-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/de.mo.mepantrag-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-12 14:06:16.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26767):    ... 12 more
```

I understood that it couldn't find the AttachmentProvider class, but why ? I also couldn't find the file in my platform/android directory. So where is it ? Or maybe I failed installing the plugin.. but works like charm on iOS.

Cheers Marvin

Comment: Same error here, do you remember what it was?

Comment: No sorry, I think I gave up after hours of searching and dropped the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Plugin works just fine. Just add
**de.appplant.cordova.emailcomposer.EmailComposer**
feature to your config.xml for android devices. Works fine on iOS.